# Meaning of "attention is a drawn to"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From *[Self Hypnosis for Beginners](http://www.self-hypnosis.biz/SelfHypnosisForBeginners.htm)*:

> In particular **attention is a drawn to** the way in which activity in one part or subsystem of the brain can lead quite naturally, but usually in a little time, to activity in another part.

What does *drawn* mean in the above text? I guess there is a mistake and *a drawn* should be changed to *drawn*, but I am not sure.

Comment: You are quite right. "Attention is drawn to" means "The book directs your attention to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The sentence should read,

> "In particular **attention is drawn** to the way in which activity in one part or subsystem of the brain can lead quite naturally, but usually in a little time, to activity in another part."

Your uncertainty about the use of the word "drawn" may be due to the *passive construction* of the the sentence, which needlessly obscures who or what is drawing your attention. To rephrase the sentence in an *active construction* (or "active voice" as it is sometimes called) it might read,

> This chapter will draw your attention to the way activity in one part of your brain affects activity in another part.

In both cases, "draw" or "drawn" means "to focus" or "to direct" your attention.

See this link for other examples of "draw": http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/draw

("Drawn" is simply the past participle of "draw.")